# Tomcat server started but not running on browser?

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver, appserver

I've been trying to run it on browser localhost: 8080 but it says "Site can't be reached" although it says Tomcat running in the terminal

I installed it via downloading binary version from website.

```
omnis-MacBook-Air:bin omni$ sudo ./startup.sh
Password:
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/temp
Using JRE_HOME:          /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-  src/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Here's Catalina.out

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

Also here's output from running:

```
omnis-MacBook-Air:bin omni$ ps auxw | grep java
```

omni             4660   0.1  0.2  4287968  13996   ??  S    12Aug16  21:44.21 ../PlugIns/Java/jre/bin/java -XstartOnFirstThread -Xmx256m -Declipse.pluginCustomization=../../../customization.ini -Dosgi.configuration.area=../../../configuration -Dosgi.configuration.area.default=../../../configuration -Dosgi.instance.area=../../../workspace -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.library.path=../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_*/eclipse_*.so -jar ../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -nl en_US -disableApplicationUpdate -port 58088 -disableServiceFiltering
omni            37621   0.0  0.0  2453628    988 s000  S+    6:35pm   0:00.01 grep java

Here's grep tomcat

```
 omnis-MacBook-Air:bin omni$ ps auxw | grep tomcat
```

root            38084   0.1  1.0  6062688  80312 s000  S     8:54am   0:15.59 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
omni            38396   0.0  0.0  2443388    956 s000  S+    6:35pm   0:00.01 grep tomcat

---

[image]

Comment: rather than grep java try grep tomcat and see what shows up. On Linux its   ps -ef | grep tomcat so might be similar on the mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your CATALINA_BASE I suspect you downloaded and are trying to run from src rather than the actual build

Make sure you're downloading the [Core distribution](http://ftp.wayne.edu/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.36/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.36.tar.gz) and not the src (unless you want to build it yourself)

Then try running it and grep for tomcat which should show up

Comment: I installed this one. its's the same. Look at the output for grep tomcat above

Comment: when you run via the Core distro do you still get CATALINA_HOME as /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-src? has the error changed or do you still get Site can't be reached?

Comment: I can't remember but I had someone working on it and they now we can see homepage but it's not properly displayed no css. Also if I click on any link on the page it says 500 HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

look at the picture above

Comment: Ok the original problem is fixed now since Tomcat is running. It seems like you have application issues now. Your logs should have an exception stacktrace. Can you post that